# WORKDIR in a yocto recipe

Tags: yocto

When I open bitbake files (ending with .bb extension), most of the files are using the WORKDIR variable as shown below.

```
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
```

can you please tell me where this WORKDIR is defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default value of `${WORKDIR}` is defined in bitbake variables. But you can change it in the recipe. It points toward the directory where bitbake unpacks the package

You can get the value of `${WORKDIR}` from the bitbake environment

```
bitbake -e <recipe-name> | grep ^WORKDIR=
```

For a specific recipe, you can get all the variables' value by getting an environment file as:

```
bitbake -e recipe_name > env
```

Answer (score 12):

From the Yocto Project Reference Manual

> WORKDIR
>
> The pathname of the work directory in which the OpenEmbedded build system builds a recipe. This directory is located within the TMPDIR directory structure and is specific to the recipe being built and the system for which it is being built.
>
> The WORKDIR directory is defined as follows:
>
> ```
>     ${TMPDIR}/work/${MULTIMACH_TARGET_SYS}/${PN}/${EXTENDPE}${PV}-${PR}
> ```
>
> The actual directory depends on several things:
>
> ```
>    TMPDIR: The top-level build output directory
>    MULTIMACH_TARGET_SYS: The target system identifier
>    PN: The recipe name
>    EXTENDPE: The epoch - (if PE is not specified, which is usually the >case for most recipes, then EXTENDPE is blank)
>    PV: The recipe version
>    PR: The recipe revision
> ```
>
> As an example, assume a Source Directory top-level folder name poky, a default Build Directory at poky/build, and a qemux86-poky-linux machine target system. Furthermore, suppose your recipe is named foo_1.3.0-r0.bb. In this case, the work directory the build system uses to build the package would be as follows:
>
> ```
>     poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86-poky-linux/foo/1.3.0-r0
> ```

http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-WORKDIR

${TMPDIR} will be the folder named "tmp" within your Yocto build directory.

Answer (score 1):

WORKDIR is definied in the following files.

```
bitbake/conf/bitbake.conf
oe-core/meta/conf/bitbake.conf
```